# problems with child Appending while parsing xml file with DOM parser in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, docx

I'm trying to parse defined docx file in android to put them in the text field , image view and table layout.
but i'm stuck on child apending.

The text file is defined and separated with an known style, who defined the headers from the topic.
but all topics are without style defined, and i trying to get them with counting what is betwen two headers and append on correct object,

here is my code but the element is appending on the same object

this is the object code + geters and seters

```
public class ObjectForPassingElements {

    Element name;
    Element content;

    int position;
    int order;
    int parrent;
    int id;
}


public List<ObjectForPassingElements> getElementByStyle(Document d,NodeList paragpraphList,String startTag,String tagname,String atribute,String atributeValue)
{

        Element paragraphElement;

        Element empty = d.createElement(startTag);
        Element elementWithTagName;
        List<ObjectForPassingElements> objListWithOutContent = new ArrayList<ObjectForPassingElements>();
        int start=0;
        int end = 0;
        int order = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<paragpraphList.getLength();i++)
            {

                paragraphElement = (Element) paragpraphList.item(i);
                //m.compareDocumentPosition(other);
                NodeList titleStyle = paragraphElement.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
                ObjectForPassingElements elementWithstyle = new ObjectForPassingElements();
                for(int j=0;j<titleStyle.getLength();j++)
                {
                    elementWithTagName = (Element) titleStyle.item(j);

                    if(elementWithTagName.getAttribute(atribute).equals(atributeValue))
                    {

                        elementWithstyle.setContent(empty);
                        elementWithstyle.setName((Element) paragpraphList.item(i));
                        elementWithstyle.setPosition(i);
                        elementWithstyle.setOrder(order);
                        objListWithOutContent.add(elementWithstyle);
                        order++;
                        //
                    }
                }
            }

            Element n;
            Node childBlankNode1 = d.createTextNode("\n\n");

        for(int i =0;i<paragpraphList.getLength();i++)
        {
            Log.d("in","inlist size"+objListWithOutContent.size()+"");
            for(int k=0;k<objListWithOutContent.size();k++)
            {
                start = objListWithOutContent.get(k).getPosition();

                if(k!=objListWithOutContent.size()-1)
                    end=objListWithOutContent.get(k+1).getPosition();
                else
                    end=paragpraphList.getLength()-1;

                if(i>=start&&i<end)
                {
                    n =(Element) paragpraphList.item(i);
                    objListWithOutContent.get(k).getContent().appendChild(n);
                }
            }
        }
        //

        for(ObjectForPassingElements obj : objListWithOutContent)
        {
            Log.d("fin",obj.getPosition()+" --- ///name "+obj.getName().getTextContent()+" name/// ---- ///content"+obj.getContent().getTextContent()+"///content  ");
        }

        return objListWithOutContent;
    }
```

here is the close example to xml document form docx document

```
    <w:p>
<w:pStyle w:val="Protocols"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00E37EC1"><w:t>HEADER 1</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id eros id nulla ultrices condimentum. Phasellus blandit pellentesque arcu, et placerat diam posuere id. Nunc feugiat, dui at pretium ultricies, enim mi placerat nibh, at bibendum urna massa id ipsum</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Fusce dignissim feugiat sapien, a consectetur diam vestibulum quis. Pellentesque aliquam scelerisque erat, at auctor sem commodo sit amet. Cras eget enim sapien,</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Aliquam elit leo, pretium ac suscipit rhoncus, eleifend vitae sem. Curabitur mattis euismod quam, vitae convallis elit sodales non.</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Curabitur vel risus vitae lacus feugiat gravida in sed lorem. Proin fringilla vehicula nulla a consectetur. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin viverra </w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Curabitur elementum condimentum enim tempus pharetra. Sed non nisl lectus. Aliquam vitae mi in diam vehicula aliquam a vitae tortor.</w:t></w:p>

<w:p>
<w:pStyle w:val="Protocols"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00E37EC1"><w:t>HEADER 2</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Cras aliquam viverra lorem, eget aliquet ipsum malesuada ut</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>Etiam non est turpis, quis posuere mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In quis lectus sapien, nec ultricies arcu.</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>tent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam et tellus at libero dignissim lobortis ut vitae nisl. Mauris sol</w:t></w:p>
<w:p><w:t>etur in, molestie non dolor. Etiam in quam purus.</w:t></w:p>
```

and here is how to call this function with needed parameters

```
    public void stripXmlTags(File f) {

    Document d;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

        d=db.parse(is);

        NodeList paragrph = d.getElementsByTagName("w:p");

        List<ObjectForPassingElements> protocolsList = new ArrayList<ObjectForPassingElements>();


        protocolsList = getElementByStyle(d,paragrph,"w:p","w:pStyle","w:val","Protocols");
```

......

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer to your question ?